# How to secure Clickhouse via the default user?

Tags: clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I have a clickhouse database someone else has installed. I am able to connect to it via the

```
clickhouse-client
```

or the

```
clickhouse-client -u default
```

command and that connects the **default** user to Clickhouse. However, I would like to change the way we connect to Clickhouse and apply a password. Since I'm not confident yet, I intend to create a super user with a username and a pasword (I want to keep **default** temporarily and only remove/change it when I'm confident with this new user). However,

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS someuser
IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password BY 'somepassword';
```

fails because **default** does not have the necessary privileges:

> DB::Exception: default: Not enough privileges. To execute this query it's necessary to have grant CREATE USER ON *.*. (ACCESS_DENIED)

Not even

```
SHOW USERS;
```

works. How can I make sure that we secure clickhouse connection with a password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `default` user just doesn't have permission to create users using SQL. Create a new XML file (name it something like my_users.xml) and place it in your `config.d` folder, and grant the `default` user permission to create new users using SQL (instead of XML configs) by enabling the `access_management` property:

```
<clickhouse>
  <users>
        <default>
            <password/>
            <access_management>1</access_management>
        </default>
    </users>
</clickhouse>
```

You can also give your new user `access_management` permission. And you can remove the `default` user with the following in your config:

```
    <users>
        <default remove="remove">
        </default>
        
        <someuser>
           ...
        </someuser>
    </users>
```